# How to update the profile picture in user profile in SharePoint online using PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user-profile-property

I want to update the profile picture in user profile in SharePoint online using PowerShell.

Has anyone implemented it?

Answer (score 1):

I used this script to update both the on-premise Active Directory and Azure AD (which will replicate to the SharePoint Online User Profile).

Required: a bunch of user pictures, named "Displayname.jpg", for example "John Doe.jpg"

```
$cred = Get-Credential #your Office 365 admin account
$MSOLSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid//?proxyMethod=RPS -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection #connection string that allows files larger than 10kb
Import-PSSession $MSOLSession #start an MSOL session

gci 'C:\UserPhotos' | % { #loop over all the picture files
   $photo = ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_.FullName)) #read the picture file
   $user = $_.BaseName #I'm using the basename as to search in AD
   $u = Get-ADUser -Filter {DisplayName -eq $user} | Set-ADUser -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=$photo} #search the user in AD and set the picture on premise
   echo $u.userPrincipalname #to see some progress when executing
   Set-UserPhoto –Identity $u.userPrincipalname -PictureData $photo -Confirm:$false #upload and set the user picture in Azure AD
}
```

Comment: Hi Meon, Thank you for the reply. I want to update the profile picture of external users, like Hotmail user to whom i have given access on my site.

Comment: I haven't tried this one yet, put the userPrincipalName of such an external user is formed like this: "name_hotmail.com#ext#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" . I'm not sure though as external users are not licensed an thus some restrictions on what you can do might apply.